# convert Owl multi item carousel in react js

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, react-router

I am new to react js, I have implement Owl carousel having multiple item slider in HTML CSS but I want it to be converted in react js can anyone help me in this regard. I have written the HTML code here and the desired output also. it shows 4 items at a time and when clicked the forward button move one item forward.
[this is the output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mUATC.png)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#news-slider").owlCarousel({
    items: 4,
    navigation: true,
    navigationText: ["", ""],
    autoPlay: false
  });
});
```

```css
/*slider CSS*/

@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Oswald:wght@200;300;400;500;600;700&display=swap');
.news-wrap {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 30px 0;
}

.news-grid {
  max-width: 258px;
  height: 268px;
  position: relative;
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 5px;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  /*box-shadow: 0px 10px 30px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.16);*/
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 25px;
}

.half {
  position: relative;
  height: 40%;
}

.news-grid img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto auto 0;
  /* position to bottom and center */
  max-height: auto;
  width: 25%;
  object-fit: cover;
}

.news-grid-txt {
  text-align: center;
  font-family: "Roboto";
  color: rgb(127, 130, 137);
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: 300;
}

.news-grid-txt h4 {
  margin-top: 10px;
  font-weight: 300;
  font-size: 18px;
}

.news-grid a {
  color: black;
  text-decoration-line: none;
}


/*Hover-Section*/

.news-grid:hover a {
  text-decoration-line: none;
}


/*OWL*/

.owl-controls .owl-buttons {
  position: relative;
}

.owl-controls .owl-prev {
  padding: 8px 17px;
  top: 1rem;
  right: 3.5rem;
  border: 1px solid rgb(228, 229, 231);
  background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
}

.owl-controls .owl-next {
  padding: 8px 17px;
  top: 1rem;
  right: 0.5rem;
  border: 1px solid rgb(228, 229, 231);
  background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
}

.owl-controls .owl-prev:after,
.owl-controls .owl-next:after {
  content: '\f104';
  font-family: FontAwesome;
  color: rgb(100, 100, 100);
  font-size: 16px;
}

.owl-controls .owl-next:after {
  content: '\f105';
}

.owl-controls .owl-prev:hover,
.owl-controls .owl-next:hover {
  background: rgb(122, 172, 179);
}

.owl-prev,
.owl-next {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}


/*End Slider*/
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Professory</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.slim.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="node_modules/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/owl-carousel/1.3.3/owl.carousel.min.css" />
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/owl-carousel/1.3.3/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>

</head>

<body>

  <div class="row slider">
    <div class="col-12 mr-0">
      <div id="news-slider" class="owl-carousel">
        <!-- 1 -->
        <div class="news-grid">
          <a href="ProfessorRating.html">
            <div class="half">
              <img src="img/professor.png" alt="">
            </div>
            <div class="news-grid-txt">
              <h4>Profesor Rating</h4>
              <p style="margin-bottom: 0px;">What is Lorem Ipsum Lorem text of the printing and type has been the industry</p>
            </div>
          </a>
        </div>
        <!-- 2 -->
        <div class="news-grid">
          <a href="SubjectRating.html">
            <div class="half">
              <img src="img/SubjectRating.png" alt="">
            </div>
            <div class="news-grid-txt">
              <h4>Subject Rating</h4>
              <p style="margin-bottom: 0px;">What is Lorem Ipsum Lorem text of the printing and type has been the industry</p>
            </div>
          </a>
        </div>
        <!-- 3 -->
        <div class="news-grid">
          <a href="Bookstore.html">
            <div class="half">
              <img src="img/book.png" alt="">
            </div>
            <div class="news-grid-txt">
              <h4>Book Store</h4>
              <p style="margin-bottom: 0px;">What is Lorem Ipsum Lorem text of the printing and type has been the industry</p>
            </div>
          </a>
        </div>
        <!-- 4 -->
        <div class="news-grid">
          <a href="ServiceProvider.html">
            <div class="half">
              <img src="img/ServiceProvider.png" alt="">
            </div>
            <div class="news-grid-txt">
              <h4>Service Provider</h4>
              <p style="margin-bottom: 0px;">What is Lorem Ipsum Lorem text of the printing and type has been the industry</p>
            </div>
          </a>
        </div>
        <!-- 5 -->
        <div class="news-grid">
          <a href="MyBackpack.html">
            <div class="half">
              <img src="img/ServiceProvider.png" alt="">
            </div>
            <div class="news-grid-txt">
              <h4>My Backpack</h4>
              <p style="margin-bottom: 0px;">What is Lorem Ipsum Lorem text of the printing and type has been the industry</p>
            </div>
          </a>
        </div>
        <!-- 6 -->
        <div class="news-grid">
          <a href="Classroom.html">
            <div class="half">
              <img src="img/ServiceProvider.png" alt="">
            </div>
            <div class="news-grid-txt">
              <h4>Classroom</h4>
              <p style="margin-bottom: 0px;">What is Lorem Ipsum Lorem text of the printing and type has been the industry</p>
            </div>
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  </script>
  <script src="node_modules/popper.js/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the `react-owl-carousel` library ?.

Please find below link to its npm documentation.
https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-owl-carousel

please find below a sandbox example by nmental
https://codesandbox.io/s/react-owl-carousel-demo-ezw97?file=/src/index.js:86-104

Comment: thank you. an upvote will be reay great!!